# Javascript change visibility dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I am trying to be fancy with this assignment and have the p tags initially invisible when the user loads the page, and only become visible when their fields they are over are either blank or invalid when clicking the submit button. For some reason it is not working when using "document.forms[0].*elementNameHere*.style.visibility = 'hidden';" same with 
"document.forms[0].*elementNameHere*.style.display= 'none';"
Can anyone see what is wrong here? Code below.

/*this is not a 'help me do my assignment' as my problem has nothing to do with requirements. I just want to make this one fancy

I am new to posting questions on stackoverflow so I'm unsure if I am posting the following code correctly: */

```
<html>
<!--Assignment 6-->
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function emptySel(){
    if(document.forms[0].teamDisplay.options[0].text == ""){
        document.forms[0].teamDisplay.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    //not becoming invis. Fix this.
    document.forms[0].fnamevalid.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.forms[0].lnamevalid.style.display = "none";
    document.forms[0].addressvalid.style.display = "none";
    document.forms[0].numbervalid.style.display = "none";
}

//baseball team name, head coach contact info
//members section: name, contact info, position played
//add/delete/modify player info.
//checkbox for guardian permission

var contactInfo = {name:"", lname:"", address:"", number:""};
var member = {contact:"", position:"", canPlay:""};
var teamInfo = {tName:"", coachInfo:"", members:""};

function fieldsNotBlank(){
    if(document.forms[0].fname.style.color != "grey" && 
       document.forms[0].lname.style.color != "grey" && 
       document.forms[0].address.style.color != "grey" && 
       document.forms[0].number.style.color != "grey"){
        document.forms[0].fnamevalid.style.visibility = "collapse";
        document.forms[0].lnamevalid.style.visibility = "collapse";
        document.forms[0].addressvalid.style.visibility = "collapse";
        document.forms[0].numbervalid.style.visibility = "collapse";
        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

function subClick(){
    if(fieldsNotBlank()){
        alert("back in subClick");
    }
}

function blurred(elem){
    if(elem.value ==''){
        elem.style.color = 'grey';
            //this CAN be removed
        switch(elem.name){
            case 'fname':
                elem.value = 'First Name';
                break;
            case 'lname':
                elem.value = 'Last Name';
                break;
            case 'address':
                elem.value = 'Address';
                break;
            case 'number':
                elem.value = 'Contact Number';
                break;
            default:
                elem.value = '';
        }
    }
}

function focused(elem){
    if(elem.style.color != 'black'){
        elem.value = '';
        elem.style.color = 'black';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="emptySel()">
<form>
<table>
<tr><td>
<p name="fnamevalid" style=" display:table; color:red; font-size:12; margin-bottom:-4px; ">*invalid</p>
<input type="textbox" style="color:grey;" name="fname" size="10" value="First Name" 
onblur="blurred(this);" onfocus="focused(this);" />
</td>
<td>
<p name="lnamevalid" style=" display:table; color:red; font-size:12; margin-bottom:-4px">*invalid</p>
<input type="textbox" style="color:grey;" name="lname" size="10" value="Last Name" 
onblur="blurred(this);" onfocus="focused(this);" />
</td>
<td>
<p name="addressvalid" style=" display:table; color:red; font-size:12; margin-bottom:-4px">*invalid</p>
<input type="textbox" style="color:grey;" name="address" size="30" value="Address" 
onblur="blurred(this);" onfocus="focused(this);" />
</td>
<td>
<p name="numbervalid" style=" display:table; color:red; font-size:12; margin-bottom:-4px">*invalid</p>
<input type="textbox" style="color:grey;" name="number" size="25" value="Contact Number" 
onblur="blurred(this);" onfocus="focused(this);" />
</td><td><input type="button" style="margin-bottom:-15px" onclick="subClick();" value="Add Player" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<select name="teamDisplay" size="9">
<option></option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to assingn an id to the form elements and then changing the properties via document.getElementById("elementId").style.display="none";  ??

Comment: Just btw: there is no such value as `collapse` for `visibility` CSS prop. Please, make your code right in general before posting a specific question.